# Fetch node issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

This code is using to bring BNB price, I want to push the price into an array. I tried Fetch in HTML page, and it worked perfect.

Comment: fetch does not exists in node and more important, NEVER EVER! Post your secret API keys!!! (or hardcode them)

Comment: What is the alternative of fetch in node js. This key created by binance for testing.. thanks for the comments

Comment: Use the node http/https module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node doesn't have `fetch` as the browser's JavaScript does.

You can try to use the Node's [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module directly or use some package like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

**UPDATE:**
However, regarding your particular case - it seems you don't have do make requests manually. You're using `node-binance-api` package that does requests under the hood. So just remove the code that invokes `fetch` at all.

**ANOTHER UPDATE:**

So finally to add a price to the array you can rewrite your function `fetchCoinPrice` like this:

```js
function fetchCoinPrice() {
  binance.prices(function(error, ticker) {
      console.log("Price of BNB: ", ticker.BNBBTC);
      array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, can you write general outline how the code is supposed to be?

Comment: @M.J. at first, you should try to at least open those doc pages and look at examples.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the link just now. shouldn't be as the following:  http.get(binance, (res) => {
    // Do stuff
  }).on('data', (data) => {
    array.push(data.price)
    console.log("tmpArray", array);
  });

Comment: I will do that but how to push the data from binance into an array?